# Check if a contract implements IERC165

Tags: interface, solidity

I have a list of contracts, some may or may not implement IERC165.  How can I check if a contract implements ERC165?

```
IERC165(proposal.targets[i]).supportsInterface(typeof(IMultiProposalDependent).interfaceId
```

Answer (score 1):

as of 0.6 try catch exists, so I just try to call the function I'm expecting.

```
try IMultiProposalDependent(proposal.targets[i]).updateResults(proposal.voteInfo) {
} catch  {
            
}
```

Probably wastes a ton of gas but I don't have a better solution atm